# Include External headers in Eclipse for C

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have some external header files in a separate directory (its the sqlite3.h). I want to be able to use them in my Eclipse CDT project. How would I include the directory to Eclipse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes.  Click Add, then File System and navigate to where the header files are stored.

(I usually select "Add to all configurations" and "Add to all languages" because it's easier to do it now than come back and change them later.)